# Find next occurrence of a specific minute in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I`m beginner in python, and there a very simple thing I need to do.

Example, If the actual time is 16:30, and the user enter with number 35, I need a datetime of 16:35.
In same example if the user enter number 20, I need 17:20 datetime (next occurrence of minute 20).

```
  initial_data = datetime.datetime.now()
  desired_time = datetime.datetime.combine(initial_data.date(), datetime.time(initial_data.hour, minute, 0))
```

This code works partially, but when the minute is in the past (example when now is 16:30, and the input is 20), the result is in the past too, but I need in next hour, like the example.

Comment: Date objects have a `.minute` attribute so if the entered time minute is larger current local time minute use `relativedelta` or `timedelta`to add an hour, else select the current hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the minutes you need to add, to reach the desired time, then add them to the initial datetime:

```
desired_time = initial_data + datetime.timedelta(
    minutes=(minute - initial_data.minute) % 60
)
```

If you want to change the seconds to 0, add `seconds=-initial_data.second` as a second parameter to the timedelta.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the condition `minute < initial_data.minute` as `True` boolean is evaluated as `1` and `False` as `0` you can use it an offset to add : add a `timedelta` with hours as the condition

Also you can use `datetime.replace()` to make you code easier

```
desired_time = initial_data.replace(minute=minute, second=0) + \
               timedelta(hours=(minute < initial_data.minute))
```

---

#### Demo

```
for minute in [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]:
    initial_data = datetime(2020, 1, 1, 23, 35, 10)

    desired_time = initial_data.replace(minute=minute, second=0) + \
                   timedelta(hours=(minute < initial_data.minute))

    print(minute, "  ", desired_time, "  ", desired_time > initial_data)

# Results
 0    2020-01-02 00:00:00    True
10    2020-01-02 00:10:00    True
20    2020-01-02 00:20:00    True
30    2020-01-02 00:30:00    True
40    2020-01-01 23:40:00    True
50    2020-01-01 23:50:00    True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can think of:

```
from datetime import datetime

FMT = '%H:%M'

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime(FMT)

hour = now.hour

minute_in = input("Enter minutes : ")

t = f'{hour}:{minute_in}'
t2 = datetime.strptime(t, FMT)

t1 = datetime.strptime(current_time, FMT)

if t1 < t2:
    print(f'{hour}:{minute_in}')
else:
    hour = now.hour
    minute = now.minute

    hour = hour + 1
    if hour > 24:
        hour = 1
        
    print(f'{hour}:{minute_in}')
```